# jQuery - DevBridge Autocomplete - Change suggestion format

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I've got the Autocomplete jQuery plugin from DevBridge working more or less how I want it to. Please see the fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/shalan/bcex6oaq/. It is a simple Suburb and City lookup whereby the user starts typing in his/her suburb and the autocomplete shows relavnt suggestions. When the user makes a selection, it will automatically populate 2 readonly textboxes below with the associated City and Postal/Zip Code. The data structure looks like this:

```
var suburbData = [
    {"value":"Eastcliffe", "data":{"city":"Westwood","code":"23145"}},    
    {"value":"Creastwich","data":{"city":"Westerlyn","code":"66365"}},    
    {"value":"South Woodbury Island","data":{"city":"Fairmoor","code":"89798"}},    
    {"value":"Faighcastle","data":{"city":"Westwood","code":"23144"}},
    {"value":"Brightkeep","data":{"city":"Merrowshore","code":"08872"}},    
    {"value":"Summerbank","data":{"city":"Wyvernfield","code":"10467"}},    
];
```

While it works great, I would like to format the suggestions list as: `Suburb, City`, but retain the `Suburb` value in the textbox from which the autocomplete function is called.

**Example:**

- If I start typing `ea`, it should show me:

  - "Eastcliffe, Westwood"
  - "Creastwich, Westerlyn"
- If I select "Eastcliffe, Westwood", then my onSelect function should run, but the value of the textbox should still remain as `Eastcliffe`.

How do I format the suggestions list in this manner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `formatResult` function it allows you to:

> formatResult: function (suggestion, currentValue) {} custom function
>   to format suggestion entry inside suggestions container, optional.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#suburb').autocomplete({
        lookup: theData,
        minChars: 1,
        formatResult: function(suggestion, currentValue){
            return suggestion.value+','+suggestion.data.city;
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j6r9ka6y/

Comment: I don't know how I missed that one! And I did read thru the Presentation Settings at https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete ... or so I thought :) Thanks Irvin

Comment: It is cool.But lets say I want to sort some suggestions (a complete list) then what I need to do.This one will trigger one by one result know ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using  `Autocomplete.formatResult`

try this JS (check demo for full code)

```
Autocomplete.formatResult = function (suggestion, currentValue) {
    var pattern = '(' + utils.escapeRegExChars(currentValue) + ')';

    return suggestion.value.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'), '<strong>$1<\/strong>')
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/&lt;(\/?strong)&gt;/g, '<$1>') + " , " + suggestion.data.city;
};
```

Comment: Link is broken fyi.

Comment: Weird, I still get: `Error 404, We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.`

Comment: am sorry. it looks like i lost the fiddle.

Comment: No worries, it happens.